# Allocate multiple parameters based on similar queries

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

In a stored procedure, I need to populate a number of parameters. The value of each parameter is based on a very similar query, identical except for the right hand operand of the where clause:

```
SELECT @param_a = f1 FROM t1 WHERE f2 = 'foo' -- this can be re-written as IN ('foo') so all queries are identical in form
SELECT @param_b = f1 FROM t1 WHERE f2 IN ('bar', 'baz)'
SELECT @param_c = f1 FROM t1 WHERE f2 IN ('qux', 'quux')
[...]
```

The actual query is much longer (multiple joined tables instead of just t1), which makes this seem like a very cumbersome way to do this. I have been thinking to store the parameters with their respective arguments in a temp table like this:

```
param      operand
---------- --------
@param_a   'foo'
@param_b   'bar', 'baz'
@param_c   'qux', 'quux'
[...]
```

And then iterate over the temp table with a cursor and each time dynamically build and execute my query, which would look something like this:

```
DECLARE my_cursor CURSOR FOR
SELECT param, operand FROM #my_temp_table

OPEN my_cursor
FETCH NEXT FROM my_cursor INTO @param, @operand

WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0
BEGIN
  SELECT @sttmt = 'SELECT @param = f1 FROM t1 WHERE f2 IN (@operand)'
  SELECT @sttmt_params = '@operand varchar(max),
                          @paramOUT varchar(max) OUTPUT'
  EXEC sp_executesql @sttmt, 
                     @sttmt_params, 
                     @operand = @operand, 
                     @paramOUT = @param[a/b/c/..] -- Here is where it goes wrong

  FETCH NEXT FROM my_cursor INTO @param, @operand
END
CLOSE my_cursor
DEALLOCATE my_cursor
```

As illustrated, the problem is that I still have to hard-code my parameter name, so that doesn't bring me any further. But maybe I am not even thinking in the right direction and there is another way of doing this? Or do I really need to copy-paste that same query for each of my parameters?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use conditional aggregation to define them in a single query without having to use a cursor:

```
SELECT @param_a = MAX(CASE WHEN f2 = 'foo' THEN f1 END),
       @param_b = MAX(CASE WHEN f2 IN ('bar', 'baz') THEN f1 END),
       @param_c = MAX(CASE WHEN f2 IN ('qux', 'quux') THEN f1 END)       
FROM t1 ;
```